# Expression related to Tellegen's theorem and signal flow graphs

Tags: signal-analysis, gradient

I'm reading the paper ["Signal Flow Graphs-Computer-Aided System Analysis and Sensitivity Calculations" by Arnold Y Lee](https://doi.org/10.1109/TCS.1974.1083832) and my question in about expression/equality (59) in the paper. The expression looks like this:

$$
\Sigma_{i=1}^r \hat{y}_i(t) * \Delta y_i(t) + \Sigma_{i=1}^q \hat{x}_i(t) * \Delta x_i(t) = \Sigma_{i=1}^m \hat{u}_i(t) * \Delta u_i(t) + \Sigma_{i=1}^q \hat{v}_i(t) * \Delta v_i(t) 
$$

I do understand the derivation of the foregoing theorem and I also follow the derivation of (40) and (46), which is:

$$
\Sigma_{i=1}^r \hat{y}_i  y_i + \Sigma_{i=1}^q \hat{x}_i x_i = \Sigma_{i=1}^m \hat{u}_i u_i + \Sigma_{i=1}^q \hat{v}_i  v_i
$$

and I also understand the steps leading to (48)

$$
\Sigma_{i=1}^r \hat{y}_i  \Delta y_i + \Sigma_{i=1}^q \hat{x}_i \Delta x_i = \Sigma_{i=1}^m \hat{u}_i \Delta u_i + \Sigma_{i=1}^q \hat{v}_i  \Delta v_i
$$

But I do not understand how to derive or explain (59).

The appearance of the convolution operator is not really explained and it is not obvious to me how to explain it. I hope some smart people here can help (?)

Comment: I would avoid linking to a copy of the paper that is not accessible from "reasonably open" sources (e.g. CiteSeer, Arxiv,....maybe ResearchGate could be added to this list although in a sort of borderline way).